# Javascript Increment counter onclick event

Tags: javascript, counter, addeventlistener

I know this might be pretty simple but I cannot see the tree from the wood atm.
Please can you help?
I have a variable whose initial value is 1 and I want to increment it by 1 every single time the user clicks on a button.
I have this code:

```
let counter = 0;



dPadRight.addEventListener("click", function increment() {
    counter++;
}
);
console.log(counter);
```

Comment: Your function should be anonymous (unnamed).  So `function () { counter++; }`

Comment: You increment `counter` on every click. That's not the case for your `console.log(counter)`.

Comment: @pwilcox I don't think that matters here. I agree with Ivar. Move the console log statement inside the event handler and it will output the current count.

Comment: @AbrarHossain, you're right about my comment about anonymous functions not mattering here.  However, regarding putting the console statement inside the event handler incrementing the counter, that's how I had originally presented my answer (see edit history).  But the OP commented that he needed to use the counter variable "from outside the function".  So I think he'll benefit from seeing the increment logic separated from the `console.log` logic into different functions.

Comment: @pwilcox I did not check your edit history before writing the comment so pardon be there. On the OP's requirement from "outside", it's a little vague. Is outside a function scope or the global scope? Assuming it is global scope, it is totally accessible by any code or function following the declaration. How useful that is will be dependent on the complexity of the script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We don't have your html markup, so below I just created a div with ID of 'dPadRight' to add the listener to.  I then referenced this in a variable in the javascript code.  I assume you're already doing something like this to have a variable called 'dPadRight'.

Based on your comment describing your need to "use [the counter] for other things", I added another "pad" identified as "otherPad".  "dPadRight" can serve to increment the counter.  "otherPad" can serve to do something with the counter.  In the code below, I just log it.

The lesson here is that if you want to use the counter after it's been incremented -- well -- then you can't be referencing it the main javascript body because that's before it's ever had the chance to increment.

```js
let dPadRight = document.querySelector('#dPadRight');
let otherPad = document.querySelector('#otherPad');

let counter = 0;

dPadRight.addEventListener("click", () => {
    counter++;
});

otherPad.addEventListener("click", () => {
    console.log(counter);
});
```

```html
<div id="dPadRight">
   click to increment counter
</div>
<br/>
<div id="otherPad">
   click to log counter
</div>
```

Comment: thanks but I want to access the counter from outside my function since I'm going to use it to do other things....I did manage to have it work with the way you did it ....any idea on how to achieve what I need?

Comment: I edited the question.  Hopefully it is of better use to you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```js
let counter = 1;


let dPadRight = document.getElementById('dPadRight');

dPadRight.addEventListener("click", function() {
   console.log(counter);
   counter++;
   if(counter > 5){
    // just to show that counter is available outside the annonymous 
    // function
     let bla = getCounterValue();
      console.log("Bla Value " + bla);
       }
 
}
);
function getCounterValue(){
   return counter;
}
```

```html
<button id="dPadRight">Increment Me </button>
```

Comment: thanks but I want to access the counter from outside my function since I'm going to use it to do other things....I did manage to have it work with the way you did it ....any idea on how to achieve what I need?

Comment: you can use it outside the function it isn't local to the block

Comment: thanks for taking the time.
that's what I thought too but unfortunately it doesn't work...it looks like it's bound to the function:
```
let counter = 1;



dPadRight.addEventListener("click", function () {
  console.log(counter);
  counter++;
});

console.log(counter);
```

Comment: I might be fixated on this now...but I don't see how your update answer can be my solution. 
Yes you can access the value of the counter in your if statement inside of the same function but given the fact that you haven't invoked  the other function named getCounterValue I don't knwo if you can access it...

Comment: Because the value is available in another block I thought this maybe make clear that it is possible to use the value outside. In your original post the problem was not with the increment this works fine the problem is that you don't call the console log again.